# Ubuntu crashes at login screen

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

I'm completely new to Linux and wanted to give it a try.

I installed Ubuntu using the windows installer.
After rebooting the PC it automatically boots into Ubuntu and get the first time run screen and then the login screen. At first the cursor won't move, or just sometimes. After a minute or so it moves like it should but nothing else works. I can't click anything and the clock remains on the same time.

When I hard reset the PC and select Ubuntu I get a message:

```
TRY (Hd0,0): NTFS5: No wubildr
TRY (Hd0,1): NTFS5: error "prefix" is not set
```

This is only for a split second.

After this I get a screen filled with artifacts, some rumbling sounds from my speakers and then the login screen appears giving me the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to run Windows then just uninstall ubuntu windows installer.

and then from right click my computer --> select manage option and do a seaperate partition for ubuntu more than 40 GB and do another partition called swap of atleast 4-5 GB.

then your ubuntu would have no problem.

Comment: I created a new partition, used the installer and put ubuntu on the new partition but the problem persists

Comment: I was saying in the above comment that do not use WUBI rather make a pendrive bootable and install from that.